# Adding Case Role to CiviCRM Cases Views

Tags: civicase, drupal-views, roles

I have created a CiviCRM Cases View. How would I add a column for "Case Manager" role to the Views? I am unable to find the field where that can be displayed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually you'll need to start with a CiviCRM Relationships View.

If you start with a view of CiviCRM Cases, you may get bad data if they have multiple open case types with different case managers.

So create a new view of CiviCRM Relationships, then in the advanced section add the Case ID relationship, then add the Contact A (the client) relationship and finally the Contact B (the case manager) relationship.

[image]

Add a Display Name field using relationship Contact A, then add another Display Name field using Contact B.

Here are all of the fields I eventually added:

[image]

Comment: This is very thorough response. Thank you very much!

Comment: I +1'ed this answer, but I wonder if there could/should be the ability to start from cases and then pull in the the Roles. My scenario is for a Union dealing with Cases involving the Employer, but some part-timers have multiple employers, so I am adding the Employer as an 'Other Party' role. And of course one person may have multiple cases open so in Views we want to show summary of each Case, Status and which of their Employers it involved with links to webforms to then trigger an 'update' action

Comment: I think there "should " be Pete but I don't think there is. I've tried multiple times to start from something other than a relationship view and it has always caused incorrect data to be displayed. Case roles seem to not be ironed out totally. They are challenging to say the least.

Comment: I don't know what version pmoz used but I repeated this in Drupal 9.

Comment: I have had exactly the same issue starting from Cases - I just could not pull it all in.  My Use Case was for a view that filtered by logged in User as the Case Manager, so I used a Contextual Filter.  The only way I could get it to work was to start with the Relationships view.  No idea why...!